# Prove the following statement.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

could someone check to see if i have a correct proof. Thank you.

If $m+n > 50$, then $m > 25$ or $n >25$ (use proof by contradiction)

So far i have:
By contradiction. If m + n > 50 and m and n are less than or equal to 25.
let m = 25 and n = 25. By definition m + n > 50. But m(25) + n(25)= 50, So this is contradiction. Hence the statement is true.

Comment: You said "*let $m=25$ and $n=25$*".  You have shown that it happens to not be true *for this very specific pair of values* for $m$ and $n$ where $m\leq 25$ and $n\leq 25$ but you have **not** shown it for **all** values of $m$ and $n$ where $m\leq 25$ and $n\leq 25$.  Your argument is incomplete.  So it doesn't work when $m=25$ and $n=25$.  What about when $m$ is possibly less and $n$ is possibly less as well?

Comment: Your argument is fine, but write it like $m\leq25$ and $n\leq25$, so $m+n\leq25+25=50$. Now you have to pay attention to what facts you are allowed to use, this will depend on your book and/or your teacher's preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only proved it for a specific case, you need to prove it in general.

Assume $m+n>50$ and $m\leq 25$ and $n\leq 25$. Then $m+n\leq50$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it so it works in general (saying "let $m = n = 25$" makes it a particular case).

Proof by contradiction:

Let's assume that $m+n > 50.$ Now suppose that $m\leq 25$ and $n \leq 25$, so then we have that $m+n \leq 50.$ Hence we would have that $m+n \leq 50 < m+n$, which is a contradiction.